# JavaScript event listener acts differently on label on radio button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to dynamically add event listeners to a group of buttons in JavaScript. However, the function only fires off properly if the actual circular button is clicked in the radio button, instead of the label for the button.

```js
function setupRadioBackground(someCard) {
    someCard.querySelectorAll(".form-check-input").forEach((child) => {
        console.log("initial test", someCard);
        child.addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.log(someCard);
            shadeBackground(someCard, child);
        })
    })
}
```

When the function initially runs, it correctly displays the card to which the event listener is being added with `initial test <card here>`. However, when I log `someCard` within the anonymous event listener function, I get different results. If I click the label, then it logs the *first someCard that had an event listener added*. But, if I click the circular button, it logs the correct card and the `shadeBackground` function works as normal.

Is there a way to have the label likewise affect the correct card?

**Minimum Reproducible Example**

To reproduce the problem, add two (or more) cards using the button. Click on the radio inputs and labels of the second card. Clicking on the radio inputs will correctly select it, while clicking on the label will select the corresponding radio input of the first card. (Use the "full page" button, to better display output.)

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#clickme");
let counter = 0;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.className = "card";
    card.id = `demoCard-${counter}`;
    card.innerHTML = `<div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" checked>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                    Default radio
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                    Second default radio
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>`
       
    document.querySelector(".output").appendChild(card);

    document.querySelector(`#demoCard-${counter}`).querySelectorAll(".form-check").forEach((child) => {
        child.addEventListener("change", function() {
            console.log("you have clicked", child);
        })
    })

    counter += 1;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="output">
    <button id="clickme">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be a `change` listener? `click` is usually the actual mouse click event. Although `<button>` elements also fire a `click` event if you press it via Enter or space, for example.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you for the suggestion. I've changed it to a `change` listener but there is still the same behavior.

Comment: How are you selecting `someCard` from the DOM?

Comment: Could you add a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet) with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? With the missing corresponding HTML it's hard to see what is actually happening in your example.

Comment: @3limin4t0r It's not *viable*, it's *verifiable*.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I'll do my best to make one, but the code is really quite long.

Comment: @Destaq It's doesn't have to be from your actual code. Just the minimal HTML with corresponding JavaScript that showcases the behaviour. [Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/kyjh70uL/2/), however this doesn't showcase the issue you have.

Comment: @3limin4t0r done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code:

1. You are having, on the same form, multiple controls with the same id. Update card's inner HTML with following code so that each card will have different name and id for radio buttons:

   ```js
   card.innerHTML = `<div class="form-check">
       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios${counter}" id="exampleRadios${counter}_1" value="option1" checked>
       <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios${counter}_1">
           Default radio
       </label>
       </div>
       <div class="form-check">
       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios${counter}" id="exampleRadios${counter}_2" value="option2">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios${counter}_2">
           Second default radio
       </label>
   </div>`
   ```
2. You want to add event listener for specific element and not again and again on all change events. Change:

   ```js
   document.querySelector(`#demoCard-${counter}`).querySelectorAll(".form-check").forEach((child) => {
     addEventListener("change", function() {
       console.log("you have clicked", child);
     })
   })
   ```

   to:

   ```js
   document.querySelector(`#demoCard-${counter}`).querySelectorAll(".form-check").forEach((child) => {
     child.addEventListener("change", function() {
       console.log("you have clicked", child);
     })
   })
   ```

that should fix your issue.

After that your form will work as expected:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#clickme");
let counter = 0;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const card = document.createElement("div");
  card.className = "card";
  card.id = `demoCard-${counter}`;
  card.innerHTML = `<div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios${counter}" id="exampleRadios${counter}_1" value="option1" checked>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios${counter}_1">
                    Default radio
                </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios${counter}" id="exampleRadios${counter}_2" value="option2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios${counter}_2">
                    Second default radio
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>`

  document.querySelector(".output").appendChild(card);

  document.querySelector(`#demoCard-${counter}`).querySelectorAll(".form-check").forEach((child) => {
    child.addEventListener("change", function() {
      console.log("you have clicked", child);
    });
  });

  counter += 1;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="output">
  <button id="clickme">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you are re-using the same *id* when you run:

> ```js
> card.innerHTML = `<div class="card-body">
>         <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
>         <div class="form-check">
>             <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" checked>
>             <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
>                 Default radio
>             </label>
>         </div>
>         <div class="form-check">
>             <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
>             <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
>                 Second default radio
>             </label>
>         </div>
>     </div>`
> ```

Each new card will use `id="exampleRadios1"` and `id="exampleRadios2"` for their radios. An *id* is supposed to be an identifier, which identifies a single element. The browser also does this assumption, so when you refer to the id with `for="exampleRadios1"` it will always refer to the first element with the `id="exampleRadios1"`.

You can solve this in multiple ways. The easiest being not assigning an *id* and *for*, but instead wrapping the `<input>` with the `<label>`.

```js
card.innerHTML = `<div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" value="option1" checked>
                Default radio
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" value="option2">
                Second default radio
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>`
```